# bind() doesn't run when onClick is used on dropdown item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, reactstrap

Why is my component method onClick not firing? when users click a dropdown item it should activate the following method using the .bind() function, but instead nothing happens, this work fine when applied in other parts of my app at a higher component level.

Typescript File where component is rendered:

```
export const Options = props => (
  <div>
    <Dropdown isOpen={props.modalDropDown} toggle={props.toggleDropDown.bind()}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>{props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle}</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {props.totalWorkloadOptions.options.map(op => (
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-invalid-this
          <DropdownItem key={op} onClick={props.appendChoiceList.bind(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle, op)}>
            {op}
          </DropdownItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenu>
      <strong> {props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionDescription} </strong>
    </Dropdown>
    <br />
  </div>
);
```

Method Im trying to bind to:

```
appendChoiceList = (title: string, selected: string) => {
    console.log('selected:' + selected);
    console.log('new choice:' + title);
    const newOptionRequest: IWorkloadRequest = {
      optionTitle: title,
      selectedOption: selected
    };

    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    for (let item of this.state.userChoices) {
      console.log(item);
      if (item.optionTitle === newOptionRequest.optionTitle) {
        // If user has already selected this before repalce it
        console.log(item);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        let i = this.state.userChoices.indexOf(item);
        console.log(i);
        this.state.userChoices[i] = newOptionRequest;
      } else {
        // if this choice has not been set before
        this.state.userChoices.push(newOptionRequest);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're trying to go for

```
onClick={() => props.appendChoiceList(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle, op)}
```

Not `.bind()`

I think you have the wrong understanding of `.bind`. Take a look at the syntax from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Ive tried the arrow function before that as follows: () => props.appendChoiceList(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle, op)   I have also tried changing the () => function being called to a normal function but still when I select a drop down item nothing appears in the console.

Comment: @Reacter23 Are you passing `appendChoiceList` to `<Options />` correctly? i.e. `<Options appendChoiceList={this.appendChoiceList) />`

Comment: The function is inherited as follows, <ModalConponent appendChoiceList={this.appendChoiceList} /> then in the reactstrap Modal I use a map function to create many <Options appendChoiceList={props.appendChoiceList} />

Comment: can you check that the props are being passed correctly? Maybe `console.log(typeof props. appendChoiceList)` to check if it's a function and get rid of any `.bind()` on the appendChoiceList calls

Comment: Says function in Firefox web browser

Comment: Is what I'm doing right now considered ok in react? I have a component that passes a function to a functional component that then passes to another functional conponent

Comment: I think it's a bit messy, but if it works, it works... i guess. (I dont think the comment section is the correct place to talk about this tbh) except it doesn't work right now. Have you checked if `DropdownItem` actually does anything when clicked on? you said you saw _no_ console outputs, right? not even the `selected` text?

Comment: Ok I'll refactor my code and send you a  PM later explaining what I done, if I can get it working I'll post here